# Cannot modify variable inside couchbase callback when using node js

Tags: node.js

I don't know if this is normal or not but when I try to access a variable inside a callback ( `Couchbase` callback ) in `node.js` it doesn't work properly.

```
   var obj = new Object();
   bucket.get(key, function(error, count) {
    bucket.get(key2, function(error, prop) {
      obj.entry = prop.value.value;
      obj[entry+"_date"] = new Date(prop.value.created_at).toString();
    })
  })
```

Am I missing something ?

Also: I can't declare the `Object` var inside the callback because I'm accessing it later on.

Comment: What exactly does not work properly?

Comment: I cannot access the obj variable inside the callback.

Comment: but do you get an error? or it is just that the prop is not being set?

Comment: That prop is not being set :) I'm not getting any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I would try this:

```
var obj = {};
   bucket.get(key, function(error, count) {
    bucket.get(key2, function(error, prop) {
      obj[entry] = prop.value.value;
      var extraKey = entry+"_date"; // ensure this is an string
      obj[extraKey] = new Date(prop.value.created_at).toString();
      console.log(obj); 
      // obj[entry] exists here
    })
  })

// but obj would be empty here :(
```

Also please keep in mind that if you use obj after the context of the callbacks, in fact you may not have the property set, simply because the callback has not executed yet. Callbacks are async. Anything you want to do with that `obj` new props should happen in the same context of where those are set. The other option is to refactor this code with `promises`, so you can have the desired order of execution.

Comment: I will give `Promises` a try. Thank you for you're answer.

Comment: Not a prob... check bluebird or q. I found q a bit more easy to understand :)